# Using the decimal format (5,2) with a calculation 1/100 SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, formatting, decimal

I am having trouble and I don't believe it is syntax related as the same syntax for different calculations work correctly...

Theory:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), (1 / 100))
```

This returns 0.00 the actual answer is 0.01

Example (denominator is 100):

```
select CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), (1/P.denominator))  
From dl.Product_UnitOfMeasure p
Where p.[SKUVariant] = 'ME000965.00'
And   p.[UOM] = 'PAC';
```

This returns 0.00 the actual answer is 0.01

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Casting a value after you've already lost the accuracy is too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server does integer arithmetic, so `1/100` is really `0`.

So, just use a decimal point:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,2), (1.0 / 100))
```

If the numerator is really a column, I would change the denominator:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(5, 2), col1 / 100.0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, let's put this one down to "there aren't any stupid questions".

Thanks again.